# Kalman Filter - Optimal Way to Handle "Derived" Measurements?

Tags: filters, kalman-filters, estimation, measurement, bayesian-estimation

Ie, if you have as state variables position (**p**) and velocity (**v**), and I make low-frequency measurements of **p**, this also indirectly gives me information about **v** (since it's the derivative of **p**). What is the best way to to handle such a relationship?

A) At the update step, should I only say I've measured **p**, and rely on the filtering process, and my accumulated state-covariance matrix (**P**), to correct **v**?

B) Should I create an "extra" prediction step, either after or before my update step for the measurement of **p**, that uses my measured **p** and (relatively large) delta-time to make a high-variance prediction of **v**?

C) In my update/measurement step, should I say I've made a measurement of both **p** and 
**v**, and then somehow encode information about their interdependence into the measurement co-variance matrix (**R**)?

---

For a little more background, here's the specific situation in which I've run into the problem:

I'm working with a system where I want to estimate the position (**p**) of an object, and I make frequent measurements of acceleration (**a**) and infrequent, high-noise measurements of **p**.

I'm currently working with a codebase that does this with an Extended Kalman Filter, where it keeps as state variables **p** and **v**. It runs a "prediction" step after every acceleration measurement, in which it uses the measured **a** and delta-time to integrate and predict new **p** and **v**.  It then runs an "update"/"measurement" step for every (infrequent) **p** measurement.

The problem is this - I get occasional high-error measurements of **a**, which result in highly-erroneous **v**.  Obviously, further measurements of **a** will never correct this, but measurements of **p** should get rid of this.  And, in fact, this does seem to happen... but VERY slowly.

I was thinking that this may be partially because the only way **p** affects **v** in this system is through the covariance matrix **P** - ie, method A) from above - which seems fairly indirect.  I was wondering if there would be a better way to incorporate our knowledge of this relationship between **p** and **v** into the model, so that measurements of **p** would correct **v** faster.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll try to come back with a longer answer later, but my immediate reactions to your questions would be A) Yes, B and C) Probably not. Are you able to detect the high-error measurements of $\mathbf{a}$ in some way? If you could detect the outliers you could throw them out to mitigate their effects. You might be hard-pressed to get great performance if your sample rate of the system's position is too low compared to its dynamics.

Comment: One other thing; there should be an implicit relationship between $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ expressed in your state transition matrix. Specifically, it should express that $\mathbf{p_{k+1}} = \mathbf{p_k} + \mathbf{v_k} \Delta t$ or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ideal world you'd have the correct model and use it.
In your case, the model isn't perfect.

Yet the steps you're suggesting are based on a knowledge you have about the process - which you should incorporate into your process equation using your dynamic model matrix:

1. The classic and correct way given F matrix is built correctly according to your knowledge.
2. "Extra" prediction step will yield nothing, since $ {F}_{ik} = {F}_{ij} {F}_{jk} $ and if you reduce the time frame you should alter $ Q $ and $ R $ accordingly which should get you at the end of the chain of small steps the same $P_{k \mid k - 1}$.
3. If you don't measure V you'll must "Estimate" it somehow. Yet by definition, if your case falls under Kalman's assumptions using Kalman's filter would yield best results.

All in all, stick with the "Classic".